# error while activating graphql on Api-Platform from symfony

Tags: symfony, graphql

I try to activate GraphQL Support on symfony api-platform, but when i visit folloing route, i got error:

/api/graphql

the error message is:

```
Attempted to load class "Debug" from namespace "GraphQL\Error".
```

Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Debug" or "Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GraphQL renamed "Debug" to "DebugFlag"

> ### v14.0.0
>
> - **BREAKING:** Renamed `GraphQL\Error\Debug` to `GraphQL\Error\DebugFlag`.

Modify Core `/vendor/api-platform/core/src/GraphQl/Action/EntrypointAction.php` to:

```
...
use GraphQL\Error\DebugFlag as Debug;
...
```

Currently the error is not bug fixed:
https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/master/src/GraphQl/Action/EntrypointAction.php

**It's only a quick and durty fix!**

Answer (score 0):

I was migrating from Laravel 7 to 8 and got the same issue.
Now there is debug param in config/lighthouse.php, you can change the class from \GraphQL\Error\Debug to \GraphQL\Error\DebugFlag and it should fix the issue.

```
'debug' => \GraphQL\Error\DebugFlag::INCLUDE_DEBUG_MESSAGE | \GraphQL\Error\DebugFlag::INCLUDE_TRACE,
```

Just in case someone is looking for a solution now and doesn't want a dirty fix.